# Is it possible to have both many-to-one/one-to-many and one-to-one mapping for the same two classes?

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, one-to-many, one-to-one, many-to-one

I have two tables. I've successfully referenced the branch_id(User Table) and branch_id(Branch Table) on my user list file. On my branch controller, I want to show the list of branches with its corresponding manager. I'm new to this so I don't fully understand how this works.

Branch Table

[image: Branch Table]

User Table
[image: User table]

User.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user")
public class User {

    /......

    @ManyToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name="branch_id", referencedColumnName = "branch_id",insertable=false, updatable=false)  
    private Branch branch;


    public Branch getBranch() {
        return branch;
    }

    public void setBranch(Branch branch) {
        this.branch = branch;
    }


}
```

Branch.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="branch")
public class Branch {

    /....

    @OneToMany(targetEntity=User.class, mappedBy="branch",cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<User> user;

    public List<User> getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(List<User> user) {
        this.user = user;
    }
}
```

Do I have to declare a one-to-one mapping between branch_manager(branch_table) and id(user table) or I can use my many-to-one/one-to-many mapping? 
I tried calling the corresponding branch manager in my branch_list.jsp like this:

```
<c:forEach items="${branchList }" var="branch">
    <tr>
        <td>${branch.branch_name}</td>
        <td>${branch.user.username}</td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

but when I include "branch.user.username" it's giving me errors.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

`${branch.user.username}` will give the error obviously because you are treating as a single user object but it is list of users actually.

```
private List<User> user;
```

so try fetching like below.

```
${branch.user[0].username}
```

here you can replace zero by iterating list of users.

Comment: But there will be no relation between the branch_manager(Branch table) and the id(user table) because the previous mapping that I did was for branch_id of both user and branch table